# Get the list of sending and receiving agents in two separated filters

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, relationship, lookup

I have a fact table and a dimension in my model in Power BI:

```
ShipmentID SendingAgentCode ReceivingAgentCode
1000       12               13
1001       14               15
```

My model is like below:

[image]

I want to have two filters one for Receiving Agents and one for Sending Agents. How can I achieve that?

Also, I want to calculate the number of shipments for Receiving/Sending Agents separately.

This is what I tried:

```
SendingAgent = LOOKUPVALUE(Agent[AgentCode],Agent[AgentName],Summarize(Shipment,Shipment[SendingAgentCode]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 2 active relationships between tables. And even though you can have one active and the other inactive, it is better to delete the inactive one and create a separate table, e.g. `DimSendingAgent = ALL(DimAgent)`.

Now you can create the missing relationship to this new table. [This is a common practice](https://radacad.com/scenarios-of-using-calculated-tables-in-power-bi) for relatively small tables using Power BI.